外部サーバからのAPI実行時におこなうセキュリティの考え方について
表題の通りなのですが、自身が提供しているサービス(API)を外部サーバからリクエストしてきます
自身が提供しているサービスは会員登録後であればリクエスト可能となっています（IDPのトークン認証・検証を実施）
Web画面を介してIDPにログインしてIDトークンをリクエストしてもらえれば問題無いのですが、外部サービスがバッチ等でWeb画面を介さずに提供しているAPIにリクエストしてくる場合どのようにセキュリティを担保するのが一般的でしょうか
①双方向のIP制限
②バッチリクエスト時にIDPへのIDS/passをリクエストしてもらって認証
①は必須として、②のようなことを実施すればよいのでしょうか
※セキュリティに絶対は無いため一般的な手法をいくつか教えていただきたいです
